# Abbreviating text in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I want to achieve the equivalent of the [`StringUtils.abbreviate(String, int)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#abbreviate-java.lang.String-int-) method in Freemarker.

I am generating per-user SMS text using Freemarker templates. Most of the text is static but it contains fields that have a maximum character size. For these fields I need to be able to do the equivalent of:

```
Hello, ${abbrev(userName, 15)}, welcome to the wonderful world of example.com.
```

Keep in mind: this is just an example.

As a first cut, I tried doing it using [this sample](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html) as a guide:

```
public class AbbreviateMethod implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

    @Override
    public Object exec(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List arguments) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (arguments.size() < 2)
            throw new TemplateModelException("Needs 2 parameters");
        return (abbreviate((String) arguments.get(0), ((Integer) arguments.get(1)).intValue()));
    }

}
```

but I get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: freemarker.template.SimpleScalar cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.example.util.AbbreviateMethod.exec(AbbreviateMethod.java:26)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._eval(MethodCall.java:65)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:81)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:96)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:59)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:327)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:333)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:306)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicit call [SimpleScalar toString()](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/SimpleScalar.html) to convert to String

Change your line to :

```
return (abbreviate(arguments.get(0).toString(), ((Integer) arguments.get(1)).intValue()));
```

Comment: Also needed to cast `arguments.get(1)` to `SimpleNumber` and then get the value from it: `((SimpleNumber) arguments.get(1)).getAsNumber().intValue()`

Comment: You should use `TemplateScalarModel` and its `getAsString()`  method, and `TemplateNumberModel` and its `getAsNumber` method, rather than assuming a particular implementation. It's safer.